# Print dataframe names in for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have some dataframes named dataBul, dataMal, dataNun, dataTi and dataTar contained in a list.

```
mylist = list(dataBul, dataMal, dataNun, dataTi, dataTar)
for(i in mylist){
df.name <- deparse(substitute(i))
print(paste(replicate(100, "/"), collapse = ""),quote=FALSE)   
print(paste("Minimum/maximum value for", df.name))
print(apply(i,2,range,na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

How I print "Minimum/maximum value for xxxx". Where xxx is dataBul, dataMal, dataNun, dataTi and dataTar. With code above, it prints "Minimum/maximum value for i".

Comment: `for(df in mylist) print(min(df))` where df has to be a column because you can only calculate the minimum columnwise, or if you wanna compare different columns get the min of the mins of the columns... or if you want multiple summary-values for all the different columns of the dfs you can do : `for(df in mylist) print(summary(df))` or even easier: `lapply(mylist, summary)`

Comment: @grrgrrbla thank's for the comment, yes I already know that. But still didn't answer my question.

Comment: @vincent it's "list" in bahasa.

Comment: @cubic So in this example it should be `for (i in mylist)` shouldn't it ?